# HttpServletResponse XML to Java

Tags: java, xml, json, dom4j

I am maintaining this servlet that has a HttpServletResponse response that replies back to the client an XML message. I want to take the XML message and convert it to JSON, then send the JSON back.

I want to avoid writing my own JSON converter if possible.  Does anyone have a good method of doing this?
I googled for this: http://pvoss.wordpress.com/2009/02/26/servlet-filter-to-convert-xml-to-json/ , which is exactly what I want but they are using a hacked dom4j jar which doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly use [Json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) to roll your own filter?

Check out the [snippets](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/snippets.html) for inspiration, and see the Javadoc section on [XMLSerializer](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/xml/XMLSerializer.html)?